# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs/urls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm learning python, I'm reading a book called python crash course and I'm stuck somewhere, it gives this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs/urls'

[image]

this is my main url file

[image]

and in the learning_log/url I have the following:

[image]

I saw many people complaining about the problem but I couldn't find a solution!

Comment: Do not post images of code, instead post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `path('', include('learning_logs.urls'))` with a `.` not a `/`